# Insert multiple values in a cell JQGrid MVC3 using the HTML Helper

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

We're working on a project using JQGrid and the ASP.NET MVC3 @Html.JQGrid() helper method. We need to insert multiple values into a single cell in the row. Example the table would look like:

```
joe | address | value 1 | value 1
    |         | value 2 | value 2
----------------------------------
bob | address | value 1 | value 1
    |         | value 2 | value 2
```

If you know how to do it by using a helper that's great, but if you know how to use the JQuery syntax that will help as well and I'll convert it.

If you need more info let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not overly familiar with JQGrid, but since you say that you can use regular JQuery syntax, you could use .append or .html tags with divs inside of them (for formatting) to append or replace content.

For instance, you could use JQuery to find the td element, then append a div with the style and value

```
    var tdElement = $(tableId).find('#tdId');
```

then use

```
    tdElement.append("<div class='CSSstyle'>"+value1+"</div>")
    tdElement.append("<div class='CSSstyle'>"+value2+"</div>")
```

which is very similar to a technique that I use for generating new rows in a table.

Hope that helps.